# Simplest fix for "error: taking the address of a temporary object"?

Tags: c++, c

```
struct context* ctx = &(struct context){ 0 };
```

I am trying to use `clang++` C++ compiler to compile C code, possibly with minimal code changes.

For the above code I get error:

`error: taking the address of a temporary object of type 'struct context' [-Waddress-of-temporary]`

1. Is there a compiler switch to make it tolerate such constructs?
2. What's the smallest code change to make such code compile using`clang++`? Maybe the following?

*a)*

```
    struct context* ctx;   
    struct context tmp = { 0 };
    ctx = &(tmp);
```

*b)*

```
    struct context* ctx;   
    {
        struct context tmp = { 0 };
        ctx = &(tmp);
    }
```

Note:

- `-std=c++2a` option is used when compiling
- `clang++` seems to tolerate (support?) designated initializers
- option *b)* also compiles fine

Comment: 1. No there isn't, 2. That (or something similar) is what you should do.

Comment: C++ doesn't have [compound literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal). When compiling a C source file, it's compiled in C mode (even when using the "C++" compiler).

Comment: Also, what is the actual problem you need to solve? Why do you need to take the address of a temporary? Asking because of plain curiosity is okay, but please state so in the question. If there's a real underlying problem you want to solve, please ask about that directly instead.

Comment: And 2.b is leading to *undefined behavior* as you have a pointer to an object whose life-time has ended.

Comment: You've editted your question since my comment, option 2b is incorrect

Comment: "My check engine light is on. What's the simplest way to turn it off? Should I use black sticky tape, or should I remove the bulb?"

Comment: I'm porting C to C++, and have countless number of places where I need to replace C temporary objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a compiler switch to make it tolerate such constructs?`

`-Wno-address-of-temporary`...

But that would be just wrong. Compiling such code *in C++* will result in a dangling pointer pointing to a memory of an object whose lifetime ended. The lifetime of temporary ends on `;` in that code - after the assignment, the pointer is just invalid.

> What's the smallest code change to make such code compile using clang++? Maybe the following?

The code `b)` is error prone - it leaves a pointer pointing to an object whose lifetime has ended.

I guess the "smallest" could be:

```
// in C++
context a,*ctx=&a;
// in C
struct context a={0},*ctx=&a;
```

Och, the smallest *change* would be to move the compund literal to previous line.

```
struct context t = {0};
struct context* ctx = &t;
```

Comment: `-Wno-address-of-temporary` just removes a warning... or error?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Works! What's confusing is that I always used `-Wno-` just for silencing warnings, never for resolving errors. Mostly for C... Is this a C++ thing?

Comment: Compiler options are a "thing" of that specific compiler. Compiler options are not part of C/C++ _language_. See [your compiler documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html) about command line options that compiler support.

Comment: You should mention that with `-Wno-address-of-temporary` you just silently get a dangling pointer.

Comment: The doc says: "_This diagnostic is an error by default, but the flag -Wno-address-of-temporary can be used to disable the error._". Didn't expect to resolve errors by silencing a warning.

Comment: @Danijel There's a reason it's a error by default. You can disable the error *message*, but code will still be broken.

Answer (score 4):

In C, `(struct context){ 0 }` is [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) syntax that creates an instance of `context` with a duration of the enclosing scope (e.g. it exists for the duration of the function call or block in which it is created).

In C++ on the other hand, `(struct context){ 0 }` creates a *temporary*, it exists for the duration of the *full-expression*, usually until the first `;`. Note that `(struct context){ 0 }` is not technically C++ (GCC understands it as a compiler extension), `context{}` would be a C++ alternative, though the semantics are the same.

So in C++ mode, `struct context* ctx = &(struct context){ 0 };` would initialize `ctx` to point to a non-existent object (a dangling pointer). That's what the compiler is complaining about.

The solution could be to give this initial context a name at global or function scope:

```
struct context init_ctx = { 0 };
```

Then elsewhere in the code just use it:

```
struct context* ctx = &init_ctx;
```

That would work the same in C and C++. It even makes the code more readable (IMHO).

Comment: *"In C++ on the other hand..."* - It's worth pointing out that this syntax is not part of C++. It's a compiler extension that applies C++-like semantics to C syntax.

Comment: Both GCC & Clang refuse to compile `&(struct context){0}` with `-std=c++?? -pedantic-errors`.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

(b) is wrong, as it leaves you with a dangling pointer.

(a) is correct, but it can be shortened:

```
struct context tmp = {0};
struct context *ctx = &tmp;
```

If you no longer need to compile this as C, you can remove the `struct` keywords here.

---

> For the above code I get
> `error: taking the address of a temporary object of type 'struct context' [-Waddress-of-temporary]`
>
> Is there a compiler switch to make it tolerate such constructs?

Most likely no. Compound literals are a C-only feature.

Both GCC and Clang with `-pedantic-errors` refuse to compile this code not because you take the address of a temporary, but because it's a compound literal.

Without `-pedantic-errors` they only complain about taking the address of a temporary, meaning they treat `(struct context){0}` as `context{0}`, not as a proper compound literal (which should create a block-scope variable, not a temporary).

Answer (score 1):

Using pointers and references to temporary data leads to undefined behavior. Never do this.

You should prolong lifetime of your object and then create pointer/reference to it, but be sure it's used only in period of object's lifetime. Probably `std::shared_ptr` can help you, it will keep object alive until you loose references to it. But you shouldn't keep raw pointers to object if you switch to `std::shared_ptr`

Also you can create `static` object - it will be alive until the program end. It's *mostly* safe to use pointers/references to it, but also have some pitfalls.